# Hangfire dashboard: SqlException: Invalid column name 'Key'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I have Hangfire installed on my web server.
And it works. And i was able to access hangfire dashboard.

But suddenly today i tried to open dashboard and when trying to access http://localhost/hangfire 
i get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid column name 'Key'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action<Action> wrapCloseInAction)
Stack Query Cookies Headers
SqlException: Invalid column name 'Key'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action<Action> wrapCloseInAction)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action<Action> wrapCloseInAction)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, bool callerHasConnectionLock, bool asyncClose)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, out bool dataReady)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, string resetOptionsString)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, bool async, int timeout, out Task task, bool asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, TaskCompletionSource<object> completion, int timeout, out Task task, bool asyncWrite, string method)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, bool wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior)
Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultipleImpl(IDbConnection cnn, ref CommandDefinition command)
Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultiple(IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable<int> commandTimeout, Nullable<CommandType> commandType)
Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerMonitoringApi+<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<GetStatistics>b__0(DbConnection connection)
Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection<T>(DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func<DbConnection, T> func)
Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerMonitoringApi.GetStatistics()
System.Lazy<T>.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
System.Lazy<T>.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
System.Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
Hangfire.Dashboard.Pages.HomePage.Execute()
Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPage.TransformText(string body)
Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPageDispatcher.Dispatch(DashboardContext context)
Hangfire.Dashboard.AspNetCoreDashboardMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Since Dashboard is some internal Hangfire tool - i just don't have an idea here how is it possible to fix the issue.
As the sql is installed by Hangfire
And Hangfire is installed from nuget.

Did anyone experienced this issue?
Any idea how to make hangfire dashboard appear?

Thank you.

Comment: `key` is a reserved word in SQL you can't name a column that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.

I just realized someone renamed [Key] column in one of hangfire tables.
Is all working.